# Is there an option to control data usage when on metered connections?

Tags: networking, windows-8

When I use Windows 8 with a mobile (and often expensive) data connection (3G/4G/etc), is there I way I can limit what apps or background services use while I'm connected to mobile Internet connections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, there is! This option seems to be new in Windows 8 but it limits drivers and applications and other services from filling up your valuable data plan - Just go to the `Start Menu`, type `Devices`, and look under the `Settings` header and click `Devices`.

See screenshot for what comes up:

[image]

Just click the black/white bar to toggle between `Yes` or `No`.  Cool, huh?

Comment: Do you know where this option is on W8.1?

Answer (score 1):

For these Windows 8 restricted connections settings to work you need to set your connection as a "Metered Connection". To do this click the network icon in the system tray and then right-click your connection and click `Set as metered connection`.

Now `Windows Updates` etc will not download when connected to that network.

You might also want to try blocking traffic with either the Windows Firewall or something like [GlassWire](https://www.glasswire.com/). Block all traffic and then only allow the apps you need.