# Stop all "under-the-hood" Windows network activity

Tags: windows, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create firewall “profiles” for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/242515/create-firewall-profiles-for-windows-7)

Occasionally I tether my laptop to an iPhone and would really like Windows to stop all its' background network activities (such as checking for updates, sending telemetry, etc) at those times since I really don't want it to clog up an already bandwidth-limited 3G connection.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The amount of data sent would be extremely small we are talking less then a few MB more then likely.  You don't indicate which version of Windows.  Windows would only send telemetry data if you enabled it in the first place.

Comment: Also see [Is there an option to control data usage when on metered connections?](http://superuser.com/questions/490185/is-there-an-option-to-control-data-usage-when-on-metered-connections) for an in-built setting in Windows 8.

Comment: @Karan: Windows wouldn't know it's on a metered connection, though. To Windows, it's a normal WiFi connection.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody else asked a very similar question a few days ago. You can install a third party firewall and set it to block all outbound network activity and specifically ask it to flag whenever a program attempts to communicate over the network. That way you can specifically allow the programs you need to use, such as internet explorer.